# Clojurescript Swap! and multiple assoc-in

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, om

Trying to make a piece of code better looking.

I have the following in Clojurescript:

```
(swap! app-state assoc-in [:lastresults] [])
(swap! app-state assoc-in [:error] false)
(swap! app-state assoc-in [:computing] true)
```

Sometimes more. Any idea on how to turn this in a cleaner multi-assignment.

I am looking at something like:

```
 (swap! app-state assoc-in
      [:lastresults] []
      [:error] false
      [:computing] true)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need `assoc-in` for just one level. This would work for your example:

```
(swap! app-state assoc 
       :lastresults [] 
       :error false 
       :computing true)
```

Comment: Works perfect for my case.